# How to display the non-whitespace character count of a visual selection in Vim?

Tags: shell, vim, piping

I want to count the characters without whitespace of a visual selection.
Intuitively, I tried the following

```
:'<,'>w !tr -d [:blank:] | wc -m
```

But vim does not like it.

Comment: your command won't (always) give what you want. `'<,'>` is line based range. it could have bigger range of your "visual selection" think about you select the text in `char-wise` or `block-wise`

Comment: Does using the plugin ['vis.vim'](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=1195) help?  `:'<,'>B !tr -d '[:space:]' | wc -m`

Comment: There is also a question about counting in vim on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/questions/149854/how-can-i-get-gvim-to-display-the-character-count-of-the-current-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must escape special character for the shell, and use `[:space:]` better because it will delete also the newline character. It should be:

```
:'<,'>w !tr -d '[:space:]' | wc -m
```

Answer (score 5):

This is possible with the following substitute command:

```
:'<,'>s/\%V\S//gn
```

The two magical ingredients are

1. the `n` flag of the substitute command. What it does is

   > Report the number of matches, do not actually substitute. (...) Useful to count items.

   See [`:h :s_flags`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#%3as_flags), and check out [`:h count-items`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tips.html#count-items), too.
2. the zero-width atom `\%V`. It matches only inside the Visual selection. As a zero-width match it makes an assertion about the following atom `\S` "non-space", which is to match only when inside the Visual selection. See [`:h /\%V`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C%25V).

The whole command thus substitutes `:s` nothing `//` for every non-whitespace character `\S` inside the Visual selection `\%V`, globally `g` – only that it doesn't actually carry out any substitutions but instead reports how many times it would have!

Answer (score 2):

In order to count the non-whitespace characters within a visual selection in vim, you could do a

```
:'<,'>s/\S/&/g
```

Vim will then tell how many times it replaced non-whitespace characters (`\S`) with itself (`&`), that is without actually changing the buffer.

Comment: I like your answer as well since it is vim only. Thanks.

Comment: just as it was pointed out to me, your approach also works line-wise, i.e. counting a fraction of a line does not work. Or is it possible to correct for that.

Comment: Unfortunatly, I don't know of a simple solution to operate on the text *between* `'<` and `'>`.

Comment: For reference, see built-in vim help page: `:h count-items`